# nodejs, how to get client time zone info from its ServerRequest

Tags: node.js, timezone, request

Does anyone kown in NodeJS, is there any way, server side script can retrieve client's time zone information from the ServerRequest object?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

From the server request object?  The only way I know of is to map the client's IP address, which you can get from:

```
var ip = request.header('x-forwarded-for');
```

... to the timezone using something like the [geoip module](https://github.com/kuno/GeoIP).  That module uses mindzone's GeoIP data, which, [according to MindZone](http://www.maxmind.com/app/faq#timezone) can provide Timezone strings.  I don't know if the module API supports that, but in theory the data is there somewhere. It's just a matter of exposing it.  If you need actually timezone time offsets, the [time module](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-time) is probably what you want.

Simpler (and probably more accurate), if you have JS running in the client, use [Date.getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) and send that as part of your web request.

Comment: broofa, how can you send Date.getTimezoneOffset as part of the same web request that requests the html?

Comment: shanebo - you could set the offset in a cookie.  That won't work for the first request a client makes, of course, but after that you'd have the info available on every request made to the server.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking you originally meant on the same request, hence, my curiosity. Thanks for the response!